# After migration to 2.2.1, all public assets, including javascripts and css return 404 in PROD mode

Tags: playframework-2.2

I migrated to 2.2.1 one week ago and I am encountring some serious issues, my project worked fine in 2.1.5.

Since earliest play2 versions, I have been using the following procedure to access my public assets (copy pasted from the official doc):

-> routes file :

```
GET   /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

in template file:

```
<link href="@{routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.css")}" rel="stylesheet">
```

without any problem.

However, now that I upgraded to 2.2.1, it's only working in DEV mode (play debug / run), in PROD, all my assets URLs return 404 errors.

I tought it was a packaging problem, checked the main jar file, I could see the public folder and the various *.js and *css files so they seem to be properly included. Also the generated URLs look clean :

```
http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css
```

I use a single module layout and develop on windows 7. I tried deploying on a linux debian 6 but had exactly the same issue.

I would appreciate any help, it seems that I am not the only one having this problem but no information about a possible fix yet... Reverting to 2.1.5 would be a difficult task because 2.2 introduced some serious incompatibilities in the API and required many code changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause of the problem by removing all dependencies from my project one by one. 
One of the plugin I am using (Japid) was compiled with an earlier version of play 2.2.x and was incompatible with 2.2.1, that caused problems with assets routing.

Fortunately, japid author has been very responsive and fixed the issue. (see release 0.9.14.1)

Answer (score 0):

You should have `/assets/*file` instead of `/assets*file` in your routes file but I doubt this will resolve your problem.

If you have other specific routes for some assets, make sure the general `GET /assets/*file` is the last one in your routes file.

Comment: In fact, my file is correct, it is a typo I introduced while trying to make the line fit into the SO textarea. Btw this is the only assets router I am using.

Comment: Do you use the script in `target/universal/stage/bin` to start your application?

Comment: I use a modified version of the one found in the "dist" output (target/universal/theproject.zip). I just replaced the -cp arguments enumerating all files in lib with "lib\\*"; because windows doesn't accept command lines that exceed a certain length.

Comment: Ok, I don't see any reason how this could be the origin of your problem. I guess the simplest way to make sure there is nothing wrong project wise is to try to push your application on a PaaS (Let me suggest [Clever Cloud](http://www.clever-cloud.com/en/) which won't cost you anything unless you exceed your free credit and choose to buy more). From there you will know if it is your project itself or the way you start it in production which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but I had to revert back to play 2.1.5 because I have already spent more time on this problem that I could afford to. I am going to have a look if I can reproduce the issue with a smaller project. I also posted the question on the play! mailing list, hoping that I am not the only one.